# How can I show my app in the menu that is displayed when text is selected in another iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say I am in Safari and I select some text on a web page. A menu pops up that shows "Copy" and possibly other options.

How can I show my app in that menu?

(The purpose would be to send that text to my app in a custom url scheme.)

**Edit:**

I thought I saw this behavior in safari, but I was mistaken. It was in an app called Equipd.

Here is an example:

![enter image description here][2]

Is this due to a collaboration between Equipd and Pleco? Or can Equipd just do this because it knows about Pleco's custom url scheme? Or is something else going on here?

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to edit this kind of menu without using jailbreak-methods. But Apple won't allow these kind of methods in their App Store apps.

But you can use the new App Extensions which Apple introduced with iOS 8. You should check the [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH20-SW1) Apple provides.

There are different extension-types. What you will need is the **Share Extension**.

Comment: I added a screenshot to make sure everyone understands what I am talking about.

Comment: It's the only choice you have. It's not possible to edit this kind of menu without using jailbreak-methods. But Apple won't allow these kind of methods in their App Store apps.